# Can't to use POST to display JSP in SPring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

With Spring 3 MVC, if I use GET method to resolve JSP, it works fine.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my_profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveMethod(@ModelAttribute("myBasicInfoForm") MyBasicInfoForm myBasicInfoForm,  HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException{
    return  "/testmyprofile";
}
```

I call saveMethod() through another method in controoler as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateProfile(@ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm myForm, HttpServletRequest request){ logger.debug("<-- log message"); return "redirect:/my_profile"; }
```

This method is called by HTML form:

```
<form:form id="ss_fp_basic_info" action="updateProfile" modelAttribute="myBasicInfoForm" method="post">
```

but if I change to POST method, I get the following error, appreciate if you can help:

```
    [6/20/12 11:23:36:118 EDT] 0000001f SystemOut     O 
[ERROR,BaseController] BaseController - handleException
    org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodResolver.resolveHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:623)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
```

Comment: On changing to POST method, how are you accessing the method `saveMethod`? With a form ? Can you post the html form ?

Comment: you've changed RequestMethod to post but you're still sending GETs?

Comment: I edit the original message by adding the HTML form

Comment: What do you change from GET to POST? Show us the code before the change, and the code after the change.

Comment: before: @RequestMapping(value="/my_profile", method = RequestMethod.GET) public String saveMethod(@ModelAttribute("myBasicInfoForm") MyBasicInfoForm myBasicInfoForm,  HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException{     return  "/testmyprofile"; }

Comment: after: @RequestMapping(value="/my_profile", method = RequestMethod.POST) public String saveMethod(@ModelAttribute("myBasicInfoForm") MyBasicInfoForm myBasicInfoForm, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException{ return "/testmyprofile"; } Only change method = RequestMethod.POST

Comment: I only change method = RequestMethod.GET to method = RequestMethod.POST before saveMethod()

Comment: @JBNizet: I am also having a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958931/405-method-not-allowed-http-method-being-used-request-method-get-not-supporte#21959010). Can you take a look and let me know what is wrong?